# Android: How to getNetworkOperatorName and location from incomming/outgoing number?

Tags: android, location

I am Developing a simple application on `CallLog.Calls`. I am also following [Calllog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) .I am Getting all the call details like.. callername , caller number , calltime , duration..etc. As per the requirement I need to check the unknown number location/caller networkprovidername like *TruecallerApp* and like this image [image]
In short I want to know how can i get or trace the Caller `Locationprovidername` from the *incomming/outgoing number* in android programatically ???Is there any database i need to create with all the related data or any other way to solve this?? By using `telephonymanager.getNetworkOperatorName()` i can get the own device operator name similliraly i want to get for other number. Any Idea Please Rply soon .
Thank you :)

Comment: As per My idea You need to create database..

Comment: You cannot directly find out info about other numbers. You need a database which you can query to find these details. Exactly why truecaller crowdsources it.